# Shell Script Error: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to run a shell script file from my USB drive which has to run an executable. I got this tree:

```
USBROOT/
    script.sh
    exe/
        myExe.exe
        Data/
            {Several Images}
        Results/
            {Results to be saved}
```

My .sh file looks like this(sorry, there is some french in the code :p):

```
#!/bin/sh
data="/exe/Data/"
exe="/exe/TopHat.exe"
rep_sortie="/exe/Results/"
fichier_sortie="GPU_Vivante_iMx6_linux.txt"
#
echo "Temps d'exécution du TopHat en secondes" >> $fichier_sortie
echo "Erosion G, Erosion L, Dilatation G, Dilatation L, Reconstruction V, Reconstruction AV, DT" >> $fichier_sortie
#
list_image=`ls ${data}U1*.jpg`
#
for f in $list_image 
do
image=${f##*/} 
#echo $image >> $fichier_sortie
$exe $f ${rep_sortie}${image} >> $fichier_sortie
done
#
list_image=`ls ${data}U2*.jpg`
#
for f in $list_image
do
image=${f##*/} 
#echo $image >> $fichier_sortie
$exe $f ${rep_sortie}${image} >> $fichier_sortie
done
```

But when I'm running it with the command line

```
sh script.sh
```

from the USBROOT directory I got a "No such file or directory" error. After several tries, I think my problem start when I declare my variables 'data' and 'rep_sortie'. Do you know what I am doing wrong ? I dont understand why it cannot see this directory.

I checked that I have the correct end of line LF.

Baptiste

Comment: You are using full paths: `/exe/Data/` and similar. You'd better use relative: `exe/Data/`, and so on.

Comment: >< seems it can find it now ! Thanks I will try with my whole script.

Comment: mkdir if not exists OR try to check for the presence of directory before you proceed to nail down the issue. Also try using set -x before running the script to see the happenings

Comment: By inserting debug output (`echo "we are in line 14"` etc.) you will probably be able to find out at least which line gives the error message.  Keep in mind that in shell scripts an error message will not abort the script running the commands.

Comment: I had two errors the first one was just the full paths problem. I used relative and all was ok. The second one was about a variable named 'exe' while I had a directory named 'exe' which provided confusion tro linux I think. It seems ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/exe/Data/ will search for the folder named under root location of linux filesystem ("/"), i.e. where all the folders like root, home, usr, tmp and mnt are placed. And script will not find any folder with name of "exe" it will report the error u got.Always if in a path / is prefixed, it translates to root of Linux filesystem.

There is difference between "/exe/Data"(Absolute path) and "./exe/Data"(Relative Path). I suppose later one is needed according to your requirement.
AS:

./exe/Data will translate to ${PWD}/exe/Data which will surely not same as /exe/Data.
where $PWD will prefix the present working directory.

Same modifications shall be made for /exe/TopHat.exe and other locations.